# NSFileManager Not Saving

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I've been trying to use NSFileManager to cache images to the Cache directory of my sandboxed app. Unfortunately, my code doesn't seem to work.

```
- (BOOL)saveImageToCacheFolder
{
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *cachePath = [[[filemgr URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] absoluteString];
    NSString *fullpath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.jpg"];
    NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.photoData format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

    BOOL success = false;
    if (imageData != nil) {
        success = [imageData writeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullpath] atomically:true];
        if (!success) NSLog(@"Did Not Managed to save the image");
    }
    return success;
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do. First, get the default NSFileManager. Second, get the relative path to the cache directory of my app. Third, append the name of my file (here i just wrote test for now). Fourth, convert my image to NSData. Fourth, write the NSData object to the specified path.

edit: added if statement for checking if the imageData is nil

Comment: check if you are getting imageDatacheck if you are getting imageData= nil

Comment: just tried, but the imageData isn't nil. thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullpath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.jpg"];

NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.photoData format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

if (imageData != nil) {
    success = [imageData writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullpath] atomically:YES];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"Did Not Managed to save the image");
}
```

Comment: darn, still doesn't work. I'm starting to become skeptical about file write permissions. I'll check it real quick.

Comment: r u checking in device. please also check about file write permission

Comment: check my edited answer. Its  now working after restructuring code.

Comment: It's working! I checked the folder, and it's indeed creating files. Thank you for your patience! If you don't mind me asking, i looked at the changes, and it wasn't immediately obvious what exactly triggered the issue: would you mind briefly explaining it? thank you again!